# How to install jenkins plugin using chef?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, chef-infra

Currently jenkins does not have a proxy setup and I need to install a Jenkins plugin.
I am looking for some pointers in doing so using Chef.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [jenkins](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) cookbook from Chef supermarket.

Once you add the appropriate dependency in your cookbook. Then you can use this cookbook's `jenkins_plugin` resource to manage plugins. Example to install a plugin named `myplugin`:

```rb
jenkins_plugin 'myplugin' do
  version '1.0'
end
```